# Querying annotations from GDB file in .Net

Tags: arcobjects, .net, annotation, file-geodatabase-api

I have annotations in a GDB file that I need to extract to load into a non-ESRI spatial store.  It's my understanding that there isn't any tool to export annotations to a shape file.  I need to copy points, text, and style info.

I have not worked with annotations before.  My prior experience with Esri products involves writing a shape file parser in C#.Net and writing .Net code that interacts with the C API for ArcSDE to query ArcSDE.  It's my understanding that ArcSDE SE_annotation methods don't really return very much detail about annotations, so I would be open to working with ArcObjects as well.  I've been reviewing that API, however, and I'm not clear on how I would query annotations.

Can you suggest ideas or point me to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question this is nothing more than a simple cursor over a FeatureClass.

I created a geodatabase annotation dataset by exporting some labels and this is the first layer in the DataFrame. The following VBA code demonstrates how to spew out the text to the debug window but it could equally be another non-spatial table.

```
Public Sub GetText()
' Get first layer in map which is the annotation layer
Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument
Set pMXDocument = ThisDocument
Dim pMap As IMap
Set pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap
Dim pLayer As ILayer
Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
Set pFeatureLayer = pLayer

' Create a cursor
Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
Set pFeatureCursor = pFeatureLayer.Search(Nothing, False)

' loop printing text string
Dim s As String
Dim pFeature As IFeature
Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
Do While Not pFeature Is Nothing
    s = pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("TextString"))
    Debug.Print s
    Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: As a point of interest, I ended up doing this with the ESRI File Geodatabase API, http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/interoperability - much lighter weight than ArcObjects for a simple extraction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a whole lot about what I am talking about but to get this out of comments here is an answer.
If this is loose annotation you may be talking about "map annotation"

> > Annotation
>
> ArcGIS provides an annotation feature type for the storage of text in
>   the geodatabase. Storing text in the geodatabase provides the ability
>   to edit the text and more efficient drawing speeds than dynamic
>   labeling since the text positions are fixed. Geodatabase annotation
>   should not be confused with the similar map annotation, which is text
>   stored in the map's BasicGraphicsLayer. For more information on the
>   map's BasicGraphicsLayer, see Working with the map.

Above quoted from the [esri help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_labels_and_annotation/0001000000nt000000/) describing going the other direction (converting labels to annotation).
First determine if the annotation you want is in the geodatabase or as [map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/000100000018000000.htm).